# Formatting an Expression Language Value

Tags: jsp

I have a scenario where the following is happening:

I my jsp, I have a something like:  '${fg.fgWarLocation}'. This might contain values like 'NewDelhi', 'Bangalore' or 'La'Montana'.

If you notice the final value, it has got a single quote in between. This cause javascripts errors.

I need to find out a way to format this last value.Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: You show `'${fg.fgWarLocation}'` in your explanation but you need to show the context. In a normal JSP EL context, such as `<h:outputText value="${fg.fgWarLocation}"/>`, there would be no problem. Then you start to discuss JavaScript out of nowhere. We need a lot more data before we can help.

Comment: Ok.I understand your point.Here is a bit more detailed explanation: I am calling a javascript function like this:  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                            callFunction('user_table_${fg.funcGroupId}','${fg.funcGroupId}',"${fg.fgWarLocation}",'','','','${testInfo.selTestTypeId}'); 
</script>This callFunction is my JS function. In this line, ${fg.fgWarLocation} is what is causing the problem if it contains a value like "Port'DeLuis". The single quote between the letters t and D. How do i overcome this problem?

Comment: In your example, it looks like you are quoting the parameter properly, such that even with a single quote mark, it should still be acceptable JavaScript. Have you tried to run a test case where you manually inject `Port'DeLuis` into the JavaScript?